# Jsoup - Android - Parse info from Form data / input

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup, form-data

I am using Jsoup in my application and I am attempting to parse information from an a few input tags in order to add them to a url and post data automatically.

The portion of HTML I am attempting to parse is as follow:

```
<div class='theDivClass'>
    <form method="post" id="handlePurchase" name="makePurchase" action="/shop.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="ProductCode" value="A1223MN" />
        <input type="hidden" name="SystemVersion" value="3" >
        <input type="hidden" name="ProductClass" value="BOOK" />
    </form>
</div>
```

The desired output would be

```
x = A1223MN
y = 3
z = BOOK
```

I am halfway familiar with JSOUP in the sense that I am able to parse out text, images, and urls but for some reason this is not clicking for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Closing this question as it appears from all of the research I have done, you cannot pull data from "hidden" input types.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use this:

```
Elements hidden = doc.select("input[type=hidden]");
```

And then just pull the attr values from each element in `hidden`. I've just tried it and it seems to work as expected.

For completeness:

```
Map<String,String> hiddenList = new HashMap<String, String>();
Elements hidden = doc.select("input[type=hidden]");
for (Element el1 : hidden){
    hiddenList.put(el1.attr("name"),el1.attr("value");
}
```

Will give you a Map of all hidden input fields in the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
Element.select("input[name=productCode]").attr("value");
Element.select("input[name=SystemVersion]").attr("value");
Element.select("input[name=ProductClass]").attr("value");
```

Comment: I tried the code you listed above and it is still returning "empty" values.  I have made edits to my original question to possibly shine more light on the subject but I don't think the additional code effects how we pull data from it.  Is it because the "types" are hidden?  When I grab just the div class data the form and input values do not appear in the output string.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way I found:

```
FormElement f = (FormElement) doc.select("form#handlePurchase").first();
System.out.println(f.formData());
```

Result:

```
[ProductCode=A1223MN, SystemVersion=3, ProductClass=BOOK]
```